# Autolayout is scaling container superview animated at launch

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard

I have an initial view controller for my app utilizing autolayout where after the launch screen disappears, you can see the container superview scale/stretch up/down to fit the device screen properly. I'd rather the layout for the views be done before the view is visible to the user. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: In `viewWillAppear:` you can add `self.view.setNeedsLayout` and `self.view.layoutIfNeeded`

Comment: That the ticket...you should add that as an answer and get some internet points.

Comment: Ahh I had that code in `viewDidLoad`. Thanks!